# Using JDBI with a JDBC driver that does not support prepared statements

Tags: java, jdbc, amazon-athena, jdbi, presto

I'm trying to use the latest 2.x version of JDBI on top of the Presto/AWS Athena jdbc driver which does not support prepared statements.

It seems like there should be a configuration option or such that would allow you to turn off the use of prepared statements, especially if you just pass in SQL with no parameters to bind. However, the StatementBuilder interface requires a PreparedStatement return value from the create method.

Has anyone run into this or have some advice about how to use JDBI in this case? I'm using it across the rest of my project for several other databases so would prefer to keep it for consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use JDBI with a JDBC driver that doesn't support `PreparedStatement`, you have two choices:

1. JDBI is open-source. Modify the source to fit your need. If you do it in a generally useful way, you might want to post the updates back, so others can benefit it, i.e. become a *contributor*.
2. Fake it. Create a JDBC wrapper around the JDBC connection from Presto/AWS Athena, that returns a fake `PreparedStatement`, supporting only parameter-less SQL statements, i.e. throws `UnsupportedOperationException` if any of the `setXxx` methods are called. You then give the wrapped connection to JDBI.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with #2, I will probably get this code on Github at some point in case anyone else wants to do this.

Comment: @RhodesianHunter, did you every post your code up to Github?

Answer (score 3):

There is JDBC driver for Presto that supports Prepared Statements that Teradata offers for free. You can download it from their website. It should work with Athena, but you'd have to try it.

Comment: This is great advice, thanks for sharing it!

I'm going to end up taking the above suggestion's advice because I don't want to have to switch everything back over to the AWS provided driver at some point if they change something important, and it also makes authenticating easier (you can pull in permissions from the box etc.). Hopefully your advice is helpful to anyone else who might see this though!

Comment: Great! Makes sense to me.